# How to inject into Azure worker role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, dependency-injection, ninject, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure Worker Role that needs a repository. I normally use Ninject to inject these things in the constructor of objects that I create, which works fine for MVC3/4 (I'm using it with Ninject.MVC).

It doesn't work with Azure worker roles however. I need a parameterless constructor to launch the role, so constructor injection isn't an option. I tried using `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` to get my repository (from a constructor, from the `OnStart()` method and from the `Run()` method), but it returns `null` every time. I think this is because the `Application_Start()` from MVC hasn't been run yet? I don't know.

Can anyone help me by explaining how I do this? Anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671744/cannot-inject-dependencies-to-azure-workerrole-object-using-spring-net

Comment: True, but you can you the same approach

Comment: Instantiate a composition root in the class self, doesnt matter what di framework you use.

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.azure

Comment: Doesn't have a NuGet package. I think there is a way to do this out of the box, or with existing nuget packages (I use package restore to automatically download dependencies).

Comment: That a project doesn't have a NuGet package shouldn't be a deal breaker. You can just download the dll and reference it, or go to the source and extract the parts you need and incorporate that in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the answer provided in this question [Cannot inject dependencies to Azure WorkerRole object using Spring.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10671744/637425) you could work something out but then use Ninject instead of Spring.NET